# CodeIgniter route not working

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have the following routes in my routes file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['testroute'] = "main";
```

As you can see all I want is when someone goes to mydomain.com/testroute it should just route back to the default controller. However when I go to that I get a 404 error. Am I doing something wrong in the way I'm writing this route?

Comment: What happens if you go to `mydomain.com/index.php/tesroute` ?

Comment: Now I get a page that just says, "No input file specified."

Comment: And is that what your main controller does? Well, anyways, are you sure your `mod_rewrite` is working/is your `.htaccess` file set correctly?

Comment: My main controller does what it's supposed to. If I just go to the root of the domain it calles the 'main' controller just fine. I'll do a test of a traditional controller that doesn't get routed and see what happenes.

Comment: Turns out I needed to change this line in my .htaccess: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] (question mark added after index.php)

Comment: Thanks Martin for this clue..when I added that mine started to work. I removed index.php from the main file in the config and didnt realise this needed an htaccess change as well.
see:$config['index_page'] = '';

Answer (score 15):

You have to create the `.htaccess` file in your app.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please paste this code in your .htaccess file.

Comment: Had same issue. Your answer helped. Thanks

Comment: You saved my night !!!! Your answer helped my team no need to work OT until midnight.

Answer (score 1):

LoneWolfPR hit the nail on the head with his comment, you are using FastCGI which requires a different htaccess.

Can you try using this one?

https://raw.github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/develop/.htaccess

I am tempted to propose we add it into CodeIgniter 2.1-dev to save this question coming up 15 times a day. Let me know if it works or fails.

Comment: This worked for me. Note the link in the example is changing as they have many branches. Just find it in the [main page](https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/) and prepend the github url with "raw" subdomain. I put the rewrite rules in my virtual host's ```<Directory>```  and tested it on an apache2.4 with proxypass to php-fpm. I used "Option 1" of the rules + the !mod_php5 rule at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Listen, this is the stupidest answer ever, but this is my experience with the similar situation - that just happened. I was helpless, but it started working - here's how.

I have one controller, caller ReadController.php (class is called the same).
Route was the same:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "ReadController";
```

Calling it with `www.martinjovanovic.com/DSi1.5-v01/index.php/ReadController/` - worked.
But calling it with just `martinjovanovic.com/DSi1.5-v01/` just wouldn't work at all.

Base URL was that of my domain and folder: wwww.martinjovanovic.com/DSi1.5-v01/

No changes to htaccess whatsoever, I left it default (Deny from all).

1. I switched default controller back to welcome.php.
2. Made a copy, called it welcome2.php. Class renamed accordingly.
3. Changed routes to welcome2. It worked. Same welcome screen.
4. Changed index() inside welcome2.php to some echo('something'). It worked.
5. Renamed welcome2.php to read.php, class accordingly. Changed it in routes. It worked.
6. Copy-pasted entire code from original ReadController.php into read.php. It worked.

That was it. Same thing started working.

The only difference between the original ReadController.php and the new read.php was in the first line. In my new read.php I kept the first line that was actually missing in the old ReadController.php (my developer ommited it, I guess):

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

This was immediately after the opening php tag.
That was the only difference. I don't get why it made such difference. Maybe it's not about it at all. Nontheless, it worked.

And the moral of this story is: I started from what worked in the first place, and kept slowly changing it towards what I need, until it worked...